# Why am I using the deleted function 'void std::ref(const _Tp&&) [with _Tp = int]'

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor, deleted-functions

```
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>
#include<tuple>
#include<functional>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    auto p = make_pair(ref(i), ref(i++));
    p.first++;
    p.second++;
    cout << "i = " << i << endl;
}
```

For example if I use `ref()` like this, the compiler will say

> use of deleted function 'void std::ref(const _Tp&&) [with _Tp = int]'

however if my code is following

```
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>
#include<tuple>
#include<functional>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    auto p = make_pair(ref(i), ref(++i));
    p.first++;
    p.second++;
    cout << "i = " << i << endl;
}
```

I will successfully get the output `i = 3`, so I can't understand why I get so different answers.

Comment: `ref(i++)` - reference to temporary, `++i` returns reference to original variable

Comment: @BlackMoses: Please answer in _the answer section_.

Comment: i am very grateful, after reflection , i think ref(i++) is a  reference to temporary is very reasonable

Answer (score 11):

`std::ref` takes a variable and gives you something that acts like a reference to that variable.

`i++` is not a variable; it is a temporary. That's because of how post-increment works; the original value is incremented but the expression evaluates to the *old* value, and a temporary is required to hold that old value so you can read it.

`std::ref` doesn't allow you to use a temporary, in order to avoid mistakes like this one. It would be a dangling reference, otherwise.

`++i`, on the other hand, just gives you back the original variable, so you can take a reference to that just fine.

However, you can't put `i` and `++i` right next to each other like that; the two expressions are indeterminately sequenced (or something) with respect to each other. Avoid this kind of code at all costs.

Comment: I looked up the sequencing, in C++14 it was UB due to unsequenced argument side-effects, but in C++17 it will be indeterminately sequenced, i.e. the `ref(i)` may read `i` either before or after the side-effect of `++i` is complete, but it is not UB. The latter text is in as of N4606.  [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39238441/1505939)

Comment: I'm not sure that *this particular case* is UB, as the value of i is not used in the sub-expression of taking a reference to it. The general point is correct however

Comment: This problem also happens when you say vector<int> myvec{1,2,3}; ref(myvec[0]). You will get: error: use of deleted function ‘void std::ref(const _Tp&&)